# How to sum a nested case statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a query that counts deductions added and modified by clients and the same for internal support reps. I'm getting error ORA-00905 missing keyword at right after the first "END" in the query. I can't figure out how to sum nested case statements.

```
SELECT 
sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION = 'A' --added deduction
        THEN
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
END AS "Added By Clients", -- count # of client deductions    

sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION = 'A' -- added deduction
    THEN
    CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
END AS "Added by Internal Reps" -- count # of internal rep deductions    

sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION <> 'A' --modified deduction
        THEN
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
END AS "Modified By Clients", -- count # of client deductions    

sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION <> 'A' -- modified deduction
    THEN
    CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
END AS "Modified by Internal Reps" -- count # of internal rep deductions 

FROM DEDUCTIONS_TBL DED
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your syntax looks like this: `SUM(CASE...) END AS alias` Your closing parentheses is cutting your CASE statement up. Stick that last `END` inside the `SUM()`.

Comment: case _expressions_...

Comment: @JNevill got it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have nested `CASE` statements in the first place? Shouldn't it be something like

```
sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION = 'A'
        AND REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

, etc?

You're getting an error because you have two `CASE ... CASE ...` but only one `END` inside the `sum( ... )`. There's an `END` outside of that, but that's effectively just a misnested bracketing group:

```
(CASE ...) END
```

Comment: Maybe a nested case isn't what I need. ded.action can be 'A' or 'M' or 'D'. A = added. D or M = modified(for the case). ded.oper_ID = the user that added, modified or deleted. This can be either an internal rep or client depending on the :digit: So, I am trying count how many deductions were added or modified by both internal reps and clients.

Comment: @CraigB I'm not sure how that comment is related to my answer. Does my suggested code not work?

Answer (score 0):

@Jnevill's post helped me fix it. I deleted the parentheses after the first END and put it after the 2nd END, but before declaring the alias.

```
SELECT 
sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION = 'A' --added deduction
        THEN
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
END) AS "Added By Clients", -- count # of client deductions

sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION = 'A' --added deduction
        THEN
        CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
END) AS "Added by Internal Reps", -- count # of client deductions

sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION <> 'A' --modified deduction
        THEN
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
END) AS "Modified By Clients", -- count # of client deductions    

sum(CASE WHEN ded.ACTION <> 'A' -- modified deduction
    THEN
    CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(ded.oper_ID, '[[:digit:]]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END) AS "Modified by Internal Reps" -- count # of internal rep deductions
```